# Trying to run RTSP Example Application (AWS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-kinesis

I was following this tutorial right here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisvideostreams/latest/dg/examples-rtsp.html and I've managed to create docker image successfully:

```
[100%] Linking CXX executable kvs_gstreamer_multistream_sample
[100%] Built target kvs_gstreamer_multistream_sample
Removing intermediate container 37d7490a2739
 ---> ad3e31c322f1
Step 7/11 : COPY start_rtsp_in_docker.sh /opt/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-producer-sdk-cpp/build/
 ---> abad1e5ff4d0
Step 8/11 : ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/
 ---> Running in 45e2d4d7fea1
Removing intermediate container 45e2d4d7fea1
 ---> d36b2e92ef3c
Step 9/11 : ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-producer-sdk-cpp/open-source/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
 ---> Running in b7a7f8d9cae4
Removing intermediate container b7a7f8d9cae4
 ---> a8b698c06880
Step 10/11 : ENV GST_PLUGIN_PATH=/opt/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-producer-sdk-cpp/build
 ---> Running in ab4d5a2c7eef
Removing intermediate container ab4d5a2c7eef
 ---> 443b38150f83
Step 11/11 : RUN chmod a+x ./start_rtsp_in_docker.sh
 ---> Running in 47d9e51f3df1
Removing intermediate container 47d9e51f3df1
 ---> ed554eeaae30
Successfully built ed554eeaae30
Successfully tagged rtspdockertest:latest
```

But when I try to execute: `docker run -it <IMAGE_ID> <AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID> <AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY> <RTSP_URL> <STREAM_NAME>` I get following error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"AKIAVSFF2IHQDM4GKHWP\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: What does the full `docker run -it` command look like (please remove (most of) the AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY before posting)

Comment: docker run -it ed554eeaae30 AKI** b3N** rtsp://Tapotest:654321@192.XXX.X.XXX:XXX/stream1 RetailIntelligence